# Web api Post method is not hitting from angular 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular2-routing

My web api method is not hitting from angular 2, even no error in console but same is working fine when i am checking with Jquery ajax call.

API Method---

```
// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]Customer objCustomer)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));

    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "//SerializationOverview.xml";
    System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);

    writer.Serialize(file, objCustomer);
    file.Close();
    return;
}
```

angular 2 call--- Not working

```
saveCustomer(): Observable<Customer[]>{
    var body = {"userName": "sonoo", "Age": "56000"}

     this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     var options = new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post, headers: this.headers});

     return  this.http.post("http://localhost:57899/api/values", body,options)
            .map(res => res.json().subscribe(
    (data) => console.log(data)));              
}
```

Note: Get method is working fine.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked what you are getting in Network tab in developer tools?

Comment: There is no information in network.

Comment: Could you share the response you get from `POST` method?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your ts code. Try this instead:

```
saveCustomer(): Observable<Customer[]>{
  const body = { userName: 'sonoo', Age: '56000'};    
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });    
  return this.http.post<Customer>('http://localhost:57899/api/values', body, { headers });
}
```

You also need to return the `Customer` object from your API like this:

```
return this.CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = customer.id}, customer);
```

Comment: Not working,getting error "Supplied parameter donot match any" at return, since it is expecting "requestoption" parameter not "httpheader object"